# What do DBMS_STATS.GEN_SELMAP

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

We are running a different kind of processes. And, in some part, depending if we run many different instances, the process raise **some hash execution** with the same schema which works on Project, not SYS:

```
EXEC dbms_stats.gen_selmap(:owner,:tabname,:pname,:spname,:flag,:colinfo,:selmap,:clist);
```

That execution is being called for some any default definition which we cannot find.

That cause Tablespace TEMP error ORA-01652

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Did you check [this](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/community/oracle_database/4174566.html) support article? Looks like it is something internal and should be consulted at Oracle Support.

Comment: As per this https://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/pkgs/dbms_stats.html the dbms_stats.gen_selmap is undocumented, it is called internally by Oracle to do stats collection. Do you have the stats job scheduled to run automatically in your DB ?

Comment: We are running scheduled jobs from Unix. That function we need to find the cause and disable.

Answer (score 0):

After three weeks I was found to solve the problem with my Partner's help.

If someone has the same cause just need to run:

```
DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(ownname => USER, tabname =>'MY_TABLE' ,CASCADE => TRUE, estimate_percent => 1, DEGREE => 4);
```

After the conflictive table and it will work successfully.